# Grails with commons-dbcp2 connection pool datasource

Tags: grails, apache-commons-dbcp

Background: I have 2 projects

A: Spring based java project

B: Grails project for gui

I have 2 questions which are related:

1. How can I use **org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource** in grails project instead of the default apache tomcat DataSource?
   There is a limitation with **org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource** , which only allows one initSql **String**. I want to run 2 init sql statements ["SET SCHEMA", "SET ROLE"], which is possible with dbcp2 because it takes a connectionInitSqls **List**. I also tried to combine 2 sql statements with a semicolon but tomcat datasource gave a validation error.
2. Is it possible to extend the datasource from another parent bean? I want to extend grails datasource from an abstract bean defined in my java project, the idea is to reuse common datasource properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen a performance comparison between this particular pool and the Tomcat pool, but my guess is that you'll be trading in a Ferrari that only plays one radio station for a jalopy that plays two. [Look at the comparisons of Tomcat vs the others - it's significantly faster](http://www.tomcatexpert.com/tags/connection-pool). If you don't get much traffic then maybe it won't be a big deal.

Performance issues aside, it's easy to register your own `DataSource` - just create a bean in `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy` with the correct name and yours will override the one configured by Grails. This is true of all Spring beans; if you register a new bean with the name of one configured earlier by Grails or a plugin, yours wins. and set the properties as needed:

```
import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource

beans = {

   dataSource(BasicDataSource) {
      url = '${dataSource.url}'
      driverClassName = '${dataSource.driverClassName}'
      username = '${dataSource.username}'
      password = '${dataSource.password}'
      // other valid setters - see the source or
      // javadocs for what's available
   }
}
```

Note that you must use single quotes when referring to `Config.groovy` variables (the values from `DataSource.groovy` get merged into the main config under the "dataSource" key) because that trigger's Spring property placeholder handling, which will replace the specified keys with lookups in System properties, properties files, and in Grails, the config. If you use double quotes they become GStrings and are evaluated too early and will cause an exception.

That's not enough though - in addition to a big pool performance downgrade, this would give you a valid connection pool but would eliminate two cool features that Grails adds. The `dataSource` bean you get if you don't customize anything is actually two proxies wrapping the real `dataSource`. One is a `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy` which avoids the cost of configuring a connection at the beginning of a transaction when no updates occur. It configures a `Connection` proxy that caches the method invocations (`setAutoCommit(false)`, setting the isolation level, readonly, timeout, etc.) and when you do an actual update, it applies those values to the real connection and uses that. But if you don't do any updates, you'l save that time, which is not a large savings but will add up on a busy site. The other is a `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy` which ensures that during a transaction or a Hibernate session, if you go to the `dataSource` to get a connection, you get the one being used already, so you'll be able to see active updates, read uncommitted changes, etc.

So there are really 3 datasource beans, and you'd register the one above with the name `dataSourceUnproxied`, and the others via references:

```
dataSourceUnproxied(BasicDataSource) {
   url = ...
   ...
}
dataSourceLazy(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy, ref('dataSourceUnproxied'))
dataSource(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy, ref('dataSourceLazy'))
```

---

---

Even when related, you should ask one question per question. I'll answer the second with a pointer to the code. If there are multiple datasources, and 3 beans per datasource, you'd end up with a lot of redundant code and config, so `DataSourceGrailsPlugin` does create an abstract parent bean definition with common properties and builds the real beans from that; you can see this all [in the code](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/2.4.x/grails-plugin-datasource/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/datasource/DataSourceGrailsPlugin.groovy#L150).

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciate your help!